# pass arguments in js with Node.JS

Tags: javascript

I have a module in node that I use to pass a username and password.

This is how it works in prompt:

```
node main.js --username admin --password pass
```

I'm trying to execute it in my node server via browser with:

```
const bundle = require ('./js/main.js')("--username admin --password pass")
```

The `require` runs the app but args are not working. How to fix this?

Comment: Fixed with shelljs

Answer (score 1):

You can access the arguments passed in nodejs by accessing process.argv variable.

```
for (let i = 0; i < process.argv.length; i++) 
{
     console.log(process.argv[i])
}
```

Comment: Tks pumpkinql but that is valid for the initial js that I run with node.js at beggining. This main.js is another one that I want to run/exec everytime I do /teste
I need to pass the arguments in the code when a url is selected.